# trying to open an app already running in python in macosx

Tags: python-3.x, macos, subprocess

while trying to open an app thats had already opened using this python code

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Users/me/Desktop/App Store"]
    )
```

it just opens a new one. I want to open the one that is already running.
any ideas

I'm using python 3.10 and macosx monterey

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to open the one that is already running"? Are you trying to focus a window?

Comment: i meant a application already running

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-a", "/Users/me/Desktop/App Store"]
    )
```

taken out the "-n" fixed it

I wanted to open an application already running